# Error using a hyphen as an object property name in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, header

I'm trying to assemble a header object for an api request. One of the headers is 'Content-Type'. The hyphen is causing a compile error. Flex is giving me:

> 1050 - Cannot assign to a non-reference value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a hyphen (minus sign) in your variable name. For example, if you try to have a variable a-b = 3, Flex thinks you're talking about subtraction.

The [documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/URLRequestHeader.html) gives info about how to set headers:

```
var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
request.requestHeaders.push(header);
```

Comment: That's a huge help. But how do I parse the result when the incoming xml uses hyphens?